# jest function mocked from module doesn't detect its call when it is called by other method

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks

I am testing my custom hook here.
If signIn method is called, it calls `history.push` in any case.

```
// Test.js

import myHandler from "./useMyHandler";
import { renderHook, act } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";


const mockhistoryPush = jest.fn();
jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("react-router-dom"),
  useHistory: () => ({
    push: mockhistoryPush,
  }),
}));


describe("auth handler hook", () => {
  it("calls signin method and check user type", async () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useAuthHandler());
    const { signIn } = result.current;
    signIn("username", "1234");
    expect(Auth.signIn).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockhistoryPush).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

And the logic is

```
const redirectToMain = () => {
  history.push("/main");
};


const signIn = async (username, pwd) => {
  let user = await Auth.signIn(username, pwd);
  // work with user
  redirectToMain();
};
```

I am expecting `expect(mockhistoryPush).toBeCalled();` is true but actually it doesn't saying

```
 expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

It definitely reaches `redirectToMain` function and even console.log(history) shows that the history is mocked function.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that if code causes state change, it should be wrapped with `act` API.

Since my signIn function is returning Promise, it has to be like

```
it("calls signin method and check user type", async () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useAuthHandler());
    const { signIn } = result.current;
    await act(async () => {
      await signIn("username", "1234");
    });
    expect(Auth.signIn).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockhistoryPush).toBeCalled();
  });
```

Now it works fine. Hope it helps someone who is having the same issue.